# Programmatically generate video

Tags: animation, programming-languages

I want to dynamically generate videos.
My program needs to query a database to get certain information (height, width, color, speed, ...).
Based on this information it will generate a video of several simple 2D objects moving in certain ways.
This needs to be saved in some sort of videoformat, preferably usable in HTML5.

There will need to be several 1000s of videos like this created on a daily basis.

What is the best technology to develop this in ?
I am looking for ease of use but also the speed of generation.

I am familiar with java, flex, perl but I am definately willing to adept to another language if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using Mac, Apple's **Quartz Composer** (included free with the Developer Tools) might be useful for this purpose.

With Quartz Composer, you can easily create graphic animations, and make them parametric (so you can set input values for the animation).

Kineme's [QuartzCrystal](http://kineme.net/QuartzCrystal) provides a way (both via GUI and command line) to render these animations to QuickTime movies and image sequences.